# Launcher icon in Android not showing

Tags: android, android-launcher, graphical-logo

Are there any special guidelines to put launcher icon in Android 7.1.1 ?

Because I added a logo in manifest file and its showing in all Android versions but not in my phone. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: That "someone" is probably a different person each time. I have not voted, but this question may be regarded as too short, or lacking substantial prior effort, or not written carefully. In particular, running a spell checker prior to posting may help avoid some downvotes (its -> it's, android -> Android, i -> I, etc).

Comment: If you don't like your posts being edited, then [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing): _Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you_.

Comment: Post your code, what have you tried so far, and screenshots of what you have and what you want. Stack Overflow is about reproducible problems and solutions not about "hey, did this happen to anyone else?".

Comment: @EugenPechanec please go through the comment section, there is a green tick placed on answer. The issue is resolved.

Comment: @Pousti If you make your question complete you won't get downvoted. You're not here to get help and leave, your question may help others, but only if it's well written.

Comment: @EugenPechanec ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Manifest.xml**, please check have to set icons for both `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon"` and `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon"`:

[image]

Here is the full code :

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```